# How to collapse and concat based on an index column along the rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a large pandas dataframe with `NaN` values like this:

```
ID        NUM           val      time_duration    company           True         Data_in   restriction_time        top
1168      3023          NaN     0 days 00:00:00        0             NaN           NaN          NaN                NaN
1172      926           NaN     0 days 00:00:00        1             NaN           NaN          NaN                NaN
121       626           NaN     0 days 00:03:11      Google          NaN           NaN          NaN                NaN
121       626           NaN          NaN               3             NaN           NaN          NaN                NaN
121       626            0           NaN               4       31/01/2018 23:59    NaN    01/01/2018 00:00         NaN
121       626           NaN          NaN             Amazon          NaN           NaN          NaN                NaN
121       626           NaN          NaN               8             NaN           NaN          NaN                NaN
555       2703          NaN     0 days 00:01:35        9             NaN           NaN          NaN                NaN
555       2703          NaN          NaN              10             NaN           NaN          NaN                NaN
555       2703          NaN          NaN              11             NaN           NaN          NaN                NaN
555       2703           0           NaN              12       31/01/2018 23:59    NaN     01/01/2018 00:00        NaN
555       2703          NaN          NaN              13             NaN           NaN          NaN                NaN
```

How can I collapse and concat into a single cell all the elements of the pandas dataframe that have the same `ID`. For example:

```
ID                                NUM                 val        time_duration       company                 True                Data_in     restriction_time          top
1168                             3023                 NaN       0 days 00:00:00          0                    NaN                  NaN               NaN               NaN
1172                              926                 NaN       0 days 00:00:00          1                    NaN                  NaN               NaN               NaN
121,121,121,121,121       626,626,626,626,626          0        0 days 00:03:11     Google,3,4,Amazon,8  31/01/2018 23:59          NaN         01/01/2018 00:00        NaN
555,555,555,555,555     2703,2703,2703,2703,2703       0        0 days 00:01:35     Google,3,4,Amazon,8  31/01/2018 23:59          NaN         01/01/2018 00:00        NaN
```

As you can see all the elements that have the same `ID` are collapsed and concatenated into a single cell adding a comma to separate all the elements from the other cells. The problem here is that I don't really understand how to use pandas to deal with the `NaN` values and strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
df.index=df.ID

yourdf=df.stack().astype(str).groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(','.join).unstack().reindex(columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!